# How do you get the soapUI maven plugin to fail safe?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, soapui, maven-failsafe-plugin

AFAIK, the maven failsafe plugin ***fails safe*** because it has separate goals for running the tests and failing the build based on the tests.  These are designed to be bound to the integration-test and verify goals respectively.  This allows post-integration-test bound goals to run (shutting down the build) before the build fails.

My question is, how do I do this with the maven-soapui-plugin?  I thought I could simply specify `<testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>` in my soapui plugin config and then call the failsafe plugin verify goal, but that isn't working.  I don't think I'm not sure if I'm getting a summary file out of the soapui plugin or not.  I keep getting `Expected root element 'failsafe-summary' but found 'testsuite'` Here is a snippet of the POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        <exportAll>true</exportAll>
        <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
        <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
        <printReport>true</printReport>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>FailingTest</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${basedir}/testData/soapui-integration-tests.xml</projectFile>
                <host>localhost</host>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
          <execution>
           <phase>verify</phase>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <summaryFiles>
                <summaryFile>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite_1.xml</summaryFile>
              </summaryFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there something wrong with my POM or is this a bad approach?  Are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source extension of the soapui plugin which has a separate test-verify goal for exactly this purpose.

https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin

The following example shows the required configuration:
https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin/blob/master/src/it/test-verify_goal/one_failing_project/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK maven-failsafe-plugin can only verify success status of tests run by maven-failsafe-plugin and not by maven-soapui-plugin. It does that by reading test summary report file (failsafe-summary.xml) which has specific format.

maven-soapui-plugin could be adjusted to separate running tests from verifying test success status, to support running post-integration-test tasks (stop server, undeploy artifacts, etc.) before verification. Create a [support ticket for this to soapUI guys](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/support).

Maybe even maven-failsafe-plugin, it's verify mojo, could be extended to allow specifying different test report format ([JUnit style reports are supported by soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Reporting/junit-style-html-reports.html)) or even an xpath expression which would be used by maven-failsafe-plugin to determine if there were failed tests or not. Create a support ticket for this on [maven-failsafe-plugin issue tracker](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/issue-tracking.html).

Until those extensions are supported, and you need to do tasks on post-integration-test phase you can use [soapUI JUnit integration](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html) and have maven-failsafe-plugin run those soapUI JUnit tests.

Comment: This answer was the best when I asked the question, but changed the accepted answer to Mark Howard's since it is a better solution that has been developed since then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying this solution, and it doesn't work.
But I have found one.
To obtain de tests report of SOAPUI tests in Jenkins, I using the failsafe plugin with this configuration in the pom.xml of my Soap tests folder :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>eviware</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${basedir}/soap_project_tests.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${filePath.reports.soap}</outputFolder>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-soap-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${filePath.reports.soap}</reportsDirectory>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>soap-integration-test-verify</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The tests cases status are up to Jenkins.

Comment: So your posting an answer that you know doesn't work?  How does this help?